# Show values in line graph R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to display the values of y1_percent and y2_percent on the line graph. I tried this

```
x_value <- seq(0.05,1,0.05)
y1_percent <-seq(5,100,5)
y2_percent <-seq(2.5,50,2.5)
ggplot()+
geom_line(aes(x = x_value, y = y1_percent,colour='red',label=y1_percent))  +
geom_line(aes(x = x_value, y = y2_percent,colour='blue',label=y2_percent))  +  
  geom_text()
```

It plots the graph; however, it doesn't display the value on the graph.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? How do you want the plot to look, and what specifically is going wrong with your current attempt?

Comment: it plots the graph; however, it doesn't  display the values on the graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you well, you want to show the numbers of `y1_percent` and `y2_percent` on the two lines plotted. One way to do this is to reorganize your data into a frame, as the following:

```
df <- data.frame(y1_percent,y2_percent)
df <- stack(df)
df$x_value <- x_value
colnames(df) <- c("y_percent", "y_label", "x_value")
```

This will give you a dataframe that looks like this:

```
> df
#   y_percent      y_label x_value
#1        5.0   y1_percent    0.05
#2       10.0   y1_percent    0.10
#3       15.0   y1_percent    0.15
#..      ....   ..........    ....
#..      ....   ..........    ....
#38      45.0   y2_percent    0.90
#39      47.5   y2_percent    0.95
#40      50.0   y2_percent    1.00
```

Now, you plot your data like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x_value, y=y_percent, colour=y_label)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(aes(label=y_percent, vjust=-0.5))
```

which gives you the following plot:

[image: plot]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi TeeKea, Marked it Done! Thanks again!